# Cannot edit imported project netbeans

Tags: netbeans, project, editing

i've recently imported a project shared with my friend for school in netbeans and we have a problem.
Everytime i try to edit or delete a comment or a code line it will show a red mark and leave a trace of my editing showing me the previous state of the c ode. I would like to edit and delete lines without this feature.

Hope i made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From your first screenshot it looks like your friend using Version Control System like Git, SVN, or other. If it's the case *Yes* it will show a red mark and leave a trace of your editing in Netbeans (in other IDEs for instance JetBrains Android Studio it's blue).

In your second screenshot the errors you're getting because of ***Auto Generated*** code for your GUI created using Form Editor. And your IDE already displaying waring like this

> WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
>         regenerated by the Form Editor.

That means when you select **Design** tab and start editing (like dragging and dropping view elements) the Form Editor re-generates the code in back-end. Like below

[image: snap 1]

[image: snap 2]